# How to extract value with SOPS without the extra newline in the output?

Tags: mozilla-sops

I'm trying to extract values from a SOPS-encrypted JSON file to export them into environment variables in order to run a web app, but the extraneous newlines keeps driving me crazy.

For example, given this `test.json` (which is then encrypted with SOPS into `test.enc.json`),

```json
{
  "password": "the cake is a lie",
  "secret": "shut up about the sun"
}
```

when I try to extract `"password"`, a newline will be added to the end:

```
$ sops --extract '["password"]'  --decrypt test.enc.json)

$ echo $password
the cake is a lie

$
```

Tried trimming the newline with `tr -d "\n"` and with `sed` but no joy.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that what I really needed was `--exec-env`. From `sops --help`:

```
COMMANDS:
     exec-env    execute a command with decrypted
                 values inserted into the environment
```

When testing it out, it works like a charm:

```
$ echo $secret

$ sops exec-env test.enc.json bash
bash$ echo $secret
shut up about the sun
bash$
(exit)
$
$ echo $secret

$
```